# R:Extract values from the vector and use them in function to calculate the difference

Tags: r

i would like to extract specific values from the vector and then use them in my function. I am going to explain it on the example.

This all calculations are taking place in **shiny app**, this example is a simplified version.

**At the moment...**

I calculate the time difference of the each sample (the samples can be differentiated using ID column) between two temperature points for x axis (in the example below x1=600 --> it is a reactive value in my shiny app and x2=800 --> it is a constant value).

```
####Sample data
data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L),
               Zeit = c(0L, 180L, 360L, 420L, 600L, 604L, 0L, 180L,360L, 480L, 600L,
                        605L), Temp = c(963L, 824L, 666L, 658L, 641L,549L, 957L, 823L, 661L,
                                        660L, 642L, 562L)), .Names = c("id","Zeit", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                           12L), class = "data.frame")
####Calculating the time for x=600 (in my app it is a reactive value)
Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(a){
  with(data[data$id == a,], approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = paste(600)))$y ###in my original data it is a reactive value:paste(input$t8xzeit)
}, double(1))
datat5 <- data.frame(ID = unique(data$id), Zeit= Zt)
####Calculating the time for x=800
Zt2 <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(a){
  with(data[data$id == a,], approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = paste(800)))$y
}, double(1))
datat8 <- data.frame(ID = unique(data$id), Zeit2= Zt2)
####Merging the data
datat85 <- merge(datat5,datat8,by="ID")
####Calculating the difference
datat85$delta <- (datat85$Zeit - datat85$Zeit2)
```

**What i need to do...**

if we have **x1=600**(which is reactive value) and **x2=800**, and we want all the values between 600 and 800 by 50, we get: 600,650,700,750,800. Then i need to use every each of this value in my function: `Zt` (look in the piece of code above) as `xout =...` and create for each calculated value a new column.

Is there a way to make it somehow automatic (loop?)?It is not possible to write each time new `Zt` function, as the number of values in vector might change due to the reactive **x1** value.

Thanks very much for help!

Comment: `dat[seq(x1,x2,by=50)]`? Not certain: *"calculate time difference b/w the extracted temp values and **always temp 800**'*, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: well its hard to explain, but im trying to do my best. Well let me explain on example if we have x1=600 and x2=800, and we want all the values between 600 and 800 by 50, we get: 600,650,700,750,800. Then i need to use every each of this value in my function: **Zt** (look in the piece of code above) as `xout =...` and create a new column with calculated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the columns for a given list of `vals` by doing the following:

```
data.new <- data.frame(ID = unique(data$id))
vals <- seq(600,800,by=50)
data.new[paste("Zeit",vals,sep="")] <- sapply(vals,function(xout.input) {
  vapply(unique(data$id), function(a){
    with(data[data$id == a,], approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = xout.input))$y
  }, double(1))
})
```

This works by using `sapply` to apply `Zt` for all the desired values creating a matrix whose columns contain the results. These are stored in the new frame by assigning the matrix to the columns with the names given by `paste("Zeit",vals,sep="")`.

Then

```
> data.new
  ID  Zeit600  Zeit650  Zeit700  Zeit750  Zeit800
1  1 601.7826 504.7059 321.2658 264.3038 207.3418
2  2 602.6250 546.6667 316.6667 261.1111 205.5556
> datat85$Zeit == data.new$Zeit600
[1] TRUE TRUE
> datat85$Zeit2 == data.new$Zeit800
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

I hope this helps.